# Are there integrals in physics that do not involve a rate of change?

Tags: integration, mathematics

In physics, whenever I see the expression
$$\int_a^b f(x) \ \text{d}x$$
for some function $f(x)$, I read this as
$$\int_a^b \frac{\text{d}F(x)}{\text{d}x} \text{d}x$$
where $F(x)$ is the antiderivative of $f(x)$. In other words, I consider every Riemann integral to be concerned with integrating a "rate of change", which in this case is $\frac{\text{d}F(x)}{\text{d}x}$. I've noticed that this thinking is applicable to some cases.

For example, if $x(t)$ is a 1D displacement function, measured in meters, and $\frac{\text{d}x(t)}{\text{d}t}$ is the corresponding velocity function, measured in meters per second, then the total displacement from time $t = a$ until time $t = b$ is
$$\int_a^b \frac{\text{d}x(t)}{\text{d}t} \text{d}t$$

Is there an integral expression in physics where the integrand is not a rate of change? That is, it **does not** have the units $a/b$, where $a$ and $b$ are some arbitrary units. In the example above, and in many other integrals, I have found that the integrand has the units $a/b$.

Comment: I'm a little unsure why your questions specifies *integrands*, are you not instead asking "for a given $f(x)$ does the anti-derivative always exist?", in which case this is more of a mathematical question than a physical one.

Comment: Can you suggest an integrand outside of physics that is not a rate of change? It seems your question is not limited to physics, and has a trivial answer in the form of Newton-Leibniz theorem.

Comment: @Charlie I think the question is meant to be: are there functions which actually come up in physics which don't have an antiderivative, but whose integral functions are of interest.

Comment: @Ruslan The answer is not so trivial, and in particular can't be found in the Newton-Leibniz theorem. In fact, the answer is no, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4243315/

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos what a small world. Yes you are right, that is what I meant. I changed my question to reflect this.

Comment: What's your criterion for existence of antiderivative here? The usual definition is that there exists no combination of elementary functions that make up a closed formula for the antiderivative and so are just known by special names.

Answer (score 0):

The moment of inertia of a body of density $\rho(x,y,z)$ about the $z$ axis is given by
$$ I = \int{\rm d}x{\rm d}y{\rm d}z \ (x^2+y^2)\rho(x,y,z)$$
whose integrand is not obviously in the form of the rate of change of any quantity.

Comment: Isn't it the rate of change of the density over position? Or something along those lines anyways.

Comment: @DKNguyen that is what I was thinking. Since $\rho (x,y,z)$ has units $\frac{\text{kg}}{m^3}$ and $x^2+y^2$ has units $m^2$, then the integrand would have the units $\frac{\text{kg}}{m}$.

Comment: Since density is a Radon-Nikodym derivative, wouldn't it make more sense to think of integrals of density as Lebesgue integrals?

Answer (score 0):

If the integrals $f$ is continuous, then the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus states that $f$ has an antiderivative.